# Select coalesc max on key update?

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql query is working fine, until I try to add the absolute last row. How can I get that part working?

```
INSERT INTO posts (ssp_order, ssp_id, ssp_ss_id, ssp_c_id) 
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ssp_order),0)+1 ,
" . $sspid . "," . $ssid . "," . $cid . "
FROM posts
WHERE ssp_ss_id = " . $ssid . "
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
ssp_status = 0,
ssp_order = SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ssp_order),0)+1 FROM posts
```

(please don't worry about the safety of the variables in there)

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ssp_order),0)+1 FROM posts' at line 8`

Comment: When using a subquery, wrap it into Parentheses. Ideally, use it the way Valli mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the table used in the select statement rather than using a subquery

```
INSERT INTO posts (ssp_order, ssp_id, ssp_ss_id, ssp_c_id) 
SELECT maxssporder ,sspid,ssid,cid from
(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ssp_order),0)+1 as maxssporder,
" . $sspid . " as sspid," . $ssid . " as ssid," . $cid . " as cid
FROM posts p
WHERE ssp_ss_id = " . $ssid . ") q
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
ssp_status = 0,
ssp_order = q.maxssporder
```

Comment: Thanks! That give me `Invalid use of group function`

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the max function. Try to give a alias for coalesce you have in the select query and use that in the update query

Comment: How do you do that? Thanks!

Comment: More complicated than I thought. Thanks!